# infoWindow in google maps on multiple markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, csv

i've created a google maps, which retrieve data from a csv file. This seem to work fine, however when i loop through all the objects the infoWindow does not seem to work. i guess this is due to the fact that the `marker` variable is inside a for loop. i've tried to move the code to inside the loop, however this result in the infoWindow placed randomly on the map instead above the clicked marker. How can i achieve the infoWindow to work with multiple markers?

**db.csv example**

```
40.740;-74.18;test;haha;
40.740;-74.20;test;haha;
```

**html & java**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mapContainer">

  <div id="map"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="abc">
    <div id="popupContact">
      <section class="register">
        <h1>CAMP INFORMATIONER:</h1>
        <form method="post" action="index.html">

          <div class="reg_section personal_info">
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Campnavn">
            <textarea name="textarea" id="description" placeholder="Beskrivelse"></textarea>
          </div>


          <div>
            <span class="submit" style="text-align: left; padding: 0 10px;"><input TYPE="button"name="commit" value="Tilføj" onclick="placeMarker(currentMarker, document.getElementById('description'));"></span>
            <span class="submit" style="text-align: right; padding: 0 10px;"><input TYPE="button" name="commit" value="Fortryd" onclick="div_hide();"></span>
          </div>

        </form>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




  <script>
  var mapCanvas;
  var currentMarker;
  function initialize() {

    var myOptions = {
      center: {lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18},
      zoom : 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    mapCanvas = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), myOptions);

    var returnValue = "";
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Read the lat/long info for markers
    request.open("GET", "db.csv", false);
    request.send(null);
    returnValue = request.responseText;

    // Convert our data from the CVS file to a usable array
    var data = CSVToArray(returnValue);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {

      // Create a lat/long object readable by Google
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data[i][0]), parseFloat(data[i][1]));

      // Generate a marker from the lat/long object and add it to the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: mapCanvas,
        title: data[i][2],
        description: data[i][3]

      });



    }

    var imageBounds = {
      north: 40.773941,
      south: 40.712216,
      east: -74.12544,
      west: -74.22655
    };
    historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgx2.jpg',
    imageBounds);
    historicalOverlay.setMap(mapCanvas);

    // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(historicalOverlay, 'click', function(e) {
       console.log("clicked'");
       currentMarker = e.latLng;
       infowindow.close();
       div_show();

     });


    //Changes zoom levels when the projection is available.
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapCanvas, "projection_changed", function(){
      mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);  //Changes the MapTypeId in short time.
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE);
      setZoomLimit(mapCanvas, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
      mapCanvas.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);  //Sets the MapTypeId to original.
    });

    // InfoWindow content
var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                  '<div class="iw-title">title</div>' +
                  '<div class="iw-content">' +
                    '<p>Founded in 1824, the Porcelain Factory of Vista Alegre was the first industrial unit dedicated to porcelain production in Portugal. For the foundation and success of this risky industrial development was crucial the spirit of persistence of its founder, José Ferreira Pinto Basto. Leading figure in Portuguese society of the nineteenth century farm owner, daring dealer, wisely incorporated the liberal ideas of the century, having become "the first example of free enterprise" in Portugal.</p>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                '</div>';

    // A new Info Window is created and set content
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content,

      // Assign a maximum value for the width of the infowindow allows
      // greater control over the various content elements
      maxWidth: 350
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(mapCanvas, marker);

      //title
      document.getElementById("iw-title").innerHTML = marker.title;

      //description
      document.getElementById("iw-content p").innerHTML = marker.description;

    });

    // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapCanvas, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.close();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

      // Reference to the DIV that wraps the bottom of infowindow
      var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');

      /* Since this div is in a position prior to .gm-div style-iw.
       * We use jQuery and create a iwBackground variable,
       * and took advantage of the existing reference .gm-style-iw for the previous div with .prev().
      */
      var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

      // Removes background shadow DIV
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

      // Removes white background DIV
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

      // Moves the infowindow 115px to the right.
      iwOuter.parent().parent().css({left: '115px'});

      // Moves the shadow of the arrow 76px to the left margin.
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(1)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

      // Moves the arrow 76px to the left margin.
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').attr('style', function(i,s){ return s + 'left: 76px !important;'});

      // Changes the desired tail shadow color.
      iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'z-index' : '1'});

      // Reference to the div that groups the close button elements.
      var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

      // Apply the desired effect to the close button
      iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #fff', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #7D0F33'});

      // If the content of infowindow not exceed the set maximum height, then the gradient is removed.
      if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
        $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
      }

      // The API automatically applies 0.7 opacity to the button after the mouseout event. This function reverses this event to the desired value.
      iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
        $(this).css({opacity: '1'});
      });
    });


}
function div_show() {
  $('#abc').fadeIn(400);

}
//Function to Hide Popup
function div_hide(){
  $('#abc').fadeOut(400);
}
  function placeMarker(location, label) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: mapCanvas,
        labelContent : label
    });
    div_hide();
  }

  function setZoomLimit(map, mapTypeId){
    //Gets MapTypeRegistry
    var mapTypeRegistry = map.mapTypes;

    //Gets the specified MapType
    var mapType = mapTypeRegistry.get(mapTypeId);
    //Sets limits to MapType
    mapType.maxZoom = 15;  //It doesn't work with SATELLITE and HYBRID maptypes.
    mapType.minZoom = 15;
  }

  function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter ){
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to comma.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ";");

    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp(
        (
            // Delimiters.
            "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

            // Quoted fields.
            "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

            // Standard fields.
            "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
        ), "gi");

    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [[]];

    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;

    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData ))
    {
        // Get the delimiter that was found.
        var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

        // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
        // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
        // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
        // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
        if (strMatchedDelimiter.length && (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter))
        {
            // Since we have reached a new row of data,
            // add an empty row to our data array.
            arrData.push( [] );

        }

        // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
        // let's check to see which kind of value we
        // captured (quoted or unquoted).
        if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){
            // We found a quoted value. When we capture
            // this value, unescape any double quotes.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
                new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
                "\""
                );

        } else
        {
            // We found a non-quoted value.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];
        }

        // Now that we have our value string, let's add
        // it to the data array.
        arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return( arrData );
}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);



    </script>
    <body>
```

**CSS**

```
/*  Author : iMomen
    Website: www.iMomen.com
    E-mail : Coder@iMomen.com
*/


#mapContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right:  0px;
  margin-bottom:  0px;
  margin-top:  0px;
  position: relative;

}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}

.gm-style-mtc {
  display: none;
}

.gmnoprint {
  display: none;
}

#abc {
width:100%;
height:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
display:none;
position:fixed;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
overflow:auto;
}

div#popupContact {
  width: 350px; /*can be in percentage also.*/

  margin: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  background-color: #ffffff;


}


div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html, body {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right:  0px;
  margin-bottom:  0px;
  margin-top:  0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


a {
  color:#FF3679;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.reg_section {
  padding:0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #eee;
}
.reg_section h3 {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: #C4A2A2;
}
/* Form */
.register {
   text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;

}
.register:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  z-index: -1;
  background:rgba(255, 173, 200, 0.08);
  border-radius:7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
}
.register h1 {
  margin: -20px -20px 0;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#694551;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom:1px solid #EDEDED;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px #f5f5f5;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #f5f5f5;
}

.register input[type=text], .register input[type=password] ,.register select,.register textarea {
  width: 278px;
}
.register p.terms {
  float: left;
  line-height: 31px;
}
.register p.terms label {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.register p.terms input {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}




.register-help {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;

  color:#FFFFFF;
}
.register-help a {
  color:#FF3679;
  text-shadow:0 1px #1E0E13;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #404040 !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 13px;
}

input {
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS",tahoma;
  font-size: 14px;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] ,.register select,.register textarea {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 34px;
  color: #404040;
  background: #fff;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #c4c4c4 #d1d1d1 #d4d4d4;
  border-radius:3px;
  --webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  outline:3px solid rgba(200, 105, 137, 0.09);
  -moz-outline-radius:7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin:10px 0;
}
input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus{
  border-color:#FFF7F9;
  outline-color:rgba(254, 225, 235, 0.7);
  outline-offset: 0;
}

input[type=button] {
  padding:0 0px;
  height: 29px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  text-shadow:0 1px #4D1124;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color:#693647;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #7D0F33;

}
input[type=button]:active {
  background: #7D0F33;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.lt-ie9 input[type=text], .lt-ie9 input[type=password] {
  line-height: 34px;
}
.register select {
  padding:6px 10px;
  width: 300px;
  color: #777777;
}
.register textarea {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #404040;
}

/* About */
.about {
  margin:10px auto;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#EEA5BD;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.about a {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.about a:hover {
  color:#2F0916;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #E83671;
}

.links {
  zoom: 1;
}
.links:before, .links:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.links:after {
  clear: both;
}
.links a {
  padding: 6px 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.gm-style-iw {
    width: 350px !important;
    top: 15px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 10px 10px;

}
#iw-container {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#iw-container .iw-title {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #7D0F33;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
}
#iw-container .iw-content {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 15px 5px 20px 15px;
    max-height: 140px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.iw-subTitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.iw-bottom-gradient {
    position: absolute;
    width: 326px;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 18px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store the marker object inside an array of object. Ex:

```
var arrayOfMarkers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      // Create a lat/long object readable by Google
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data[i][0]), parseFloat(data[i][1]));
      // Generate a marker from the lat/long object and add it to the map
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: mapCanvas,
        title: data[i][2],
        description: data[i][3]
      });
      arrayOfMarkers.push(marker);
  }
```

Then use the arrayOfMarkers to iterate the event listener for each Info Windows

[Updated - Add Ground Overlay after user clicks the marker]

Please see the demo here : http://codepen.io/dannypranoto/pen/PNdvzb

All you need to do is set up a new function for creating a new Ground Overlay with parameters of imageBound

```
this.instance = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.740, -74.18),
    zoom: 13,
});

this.addGroundOverlay = function(data) {
    var instance = this.instance;
    var groundOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
    'https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mgx2.jpg',data);
    groundOverlay.setMap(instance);
}
```

Then call the function inside the `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, ...)`

```
this.addMarker = function(data) {
    var Map = this;
    var instance = this.instance;
    var content = String.format(this.contentTemplate, data.image_url, data.name, data.summary);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude),
      title: data.name
    });
    marker.setMap(instance);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      var imageBound = {
          north: 40.773941,
          south: 40.712216,
          east: -74.12544,
          west: -74.22655
      } 
      Map.addGroundOverlay(imageBound);
    });
}
```

Comment: what about this line `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {` i guess that this should be changed to since it cant access marker?

Comment: yes, you might need to iterate on each marker by adding the looping for the `event.addListener` so it might be looks like this `google.maps.event.addListener(arrayOfMarkers[i], 'click', function() {`

Comment: hmm infoWindow still does not seem to show. i guess i need to change `infowindow.open(mapCanvas, marker);` to `infowindow.open(mapCanvas, arrayOfMarkers[i]);` however still doesnt work

Comment: I think you need to create an infowindows object for each markers as well, I found this reference about multiple markers and infowindows, maybe this might helps http://you.arenot.me/2010/06/29/google-maps-api-v3-0-multiple-markers-multiple-infowindows/

Comment: Hi, I've tried to provide the example as well, hope it might helps http://codepen.io/dannypranoto/pen/PNdvzb

Comment: Thank you! could u show how i would add my overlay in this case, since structure is quite different

Comment: I've updated the codepen and the answer. Please have a check.